# how to print a string who contains variables, the string is contained is .json file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, substring

**Hello**,

I have a little problem and I am not able to fix it

I try to print a string containing a varibale and this string is also contained in a string.

like this:

```
import json

with open('example.json','r') as f:
   json_content = json.load(f)

variable = 'var'
message = json_content['message']

print(message)
```

example.json

```
{'message': 'this is a message with a {variable}'}
```

And I want to get output "this is a message with a var"

*sorry if is not very clear I'm french ^^'*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: "I try to print a string containing a varibale and this string is also contained in a string."
This is not a very clear description of what you want to achieve, you want to add string variable named "variable" in the given position of message (another string), right? Also what @DeepSpace told applies.

Comment: `json_content[message]` the variable `message` here is referred to before its assignment.

Comment: the JSON file should look like this: `{"message":"this is a message with a {variable}"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should develop more on your fundamentals, ***and*** try out your *own code* before asking a question here.

I guess what you are trying to achieve can be done like this.

```
import json

with open("example.json", "r") as f:
   json_content = json.load(f)

message = json_content["message"]
variable = "var"
print(message.format(variable=variable))

# prints
# this is a message with a var
```